# If a meromorphic function is even at the origin, can I show it even on the whole complex plain?

Tags: complex-analysis

$O^*(z_0,r)=\{z\,|\,0<\left|z-z_0\right|<r\}$

Let $f(z)$ be a meromorphic function on the complex plane, and it suffices the following two conditions:

(1) the poles of $f(z)$ is symmetrically distributed with the same even order. (i.e. $z_0$ is a pole of $f(z)$ with order k if and only if $-z_0$ is a pole of $f(z)$ with order k)

(2) $f(z)$ is even at the origin. (i.e. $f(z)=f(-z)$, $\forall z \in O^*(0, r))$

Then $f(z)$ is even on the whole complex plane.

My argument is as followed:

Let poles of $f(z)$ be $z_i$, and suppose that $0<\left|z_1\right|\leq\left|z_2\right|\leq\cdots$

Since poles of a meromorphic function is isolated, let $r_{i}$ be the distance between $z_i$ and  a closest pole near $z_i$, i.e. $r_{i}=\min_{f(y)=\infty}\left\{\left|y-z_i\right|\right\}$, then for $z\in O^*(z_1, r_1)$, $f(z)$ has the following form:
$$f(z)=\frac{h_1(z)}{(z-z_1)^k}$$
and for $z\in O^*(-z_1,r_1)$
$$f(z)=\frac{h_{-1}(z)}{(z+z_1)^k}$$
$h_1(z)$ and $h_{-1}(-z)$ are holomorphic functions in $O^*(z_1,r_1)$. Since $f(z)$ is even in $O^*(0,r)$, and according to our choice of radius r, $O^*(z_1,r_1)\cap O^*(0,r)\not=\varnothing$. For $z\in O^*(z_1,r_1)\cap O^*(0,r)$, we have $h_1(z)=(-1)^kh_{-1}(-z)$. So $h_1(z)=(-1)^kh_{-1}(-z)$ for $z\in O^*(-z_1,r_1)$, and then $f(z)=f(-z)$ for $z\in O^*(-z_1,r_1)$. The same argument goes on with the next pole and then $f(z)$ is even on the whole complex plane.

I need someone to check my argument and I wonder whether condition (1) can be weakened.

Comment: Let $g(z)=f(-z)$ meromorphic; note that $h(z)=f(z)-g(z)$ is meromorphic and identically zero in a small punctured disc, hence it is zero everywhere, so no condition on poles is necessary (the symmetry of the poles follows); now $f(z)=1/(z-1)-1/(z+1)$ shows that except for symmetry of the poles ($w$ pole then $-w$ pole) one can have any odd orders too (except that $\pm w$ have same order) except of course at zero, where poles must be of even order

Comment: @Conrad I agree. I made a little mistake. I think I need to prove that a meromorphic function which is identically zero in a small punctured disc is zero everywhere. Could you show me how to prove that? And I don't quite understand how to prove the symmetry of the poles. Thank you.

Comment: Poles are just values where $f$ is infinity so it is like with other value ($f(w)=a$ iff $f(-w)=a$); then if $f$ is zero on an open set, the usual connectivity proof applies ($A$ the set of $a$ for which $f$ is zero on a neighborhood of $a$ is non empty, open by definition and closed using the Taylor series at a limit point)

Comment: Thanks, now I understand.